# Difference between static content deploy & grunt exec

Tags: magento2, grunt

What's the difference between following commands (Magento 2)

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and grunt exec
```

When should you use which command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) is a Node Js package, so at the first time to make the Grunt commands can work, we need to install Node Js.

For instance, when run the command: `grunt clean:<theme>`, `Gruntfile.js` under Magento root folder is used. Take a look this file:

```
var _ = require('underscore'),
    path = require('path'),
    themes = require('./dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes'),
    configDir = './dev/tools/grunt/configs',
    taskDir = './dev/tools/grunt/tasks';

[
    taskDir + '/mage-minify',
    taskDir + '/deploy',
    taskDir + '/black-list-generator',
    taskDir + '/clean-black-list',
    taskDir + '/static',
    'time-grunt'
].forEach(function (task) {
    require(task)(grunt);
});
```

We can see some configs:

**1) For our theme config: `themes = require('./dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes')`, usually uses for grunt watch command.**

**2) Load config: `configDir = './dev/tools/grunt/configs'`.**

**3) Tasks: `taskDir = './dev/tools/grunt/tasks'`. We have some tasks: deployment, minify, etc.**

## Refresh themes:

```
    /**
     * Refresh themes.
     */
    refresh: function () {
        var tasks = [
            'clean',
            'exec:all'
        ];
        _.each(themes, function(theme, name) {
            tasks.push('less:' + name);
        });
        grunt.task.run(tasks);
    },
```

The refresh function is the most useful function, this function defines some tasks: `grunt clean:<theme>`, `grunt less:<theme>` and `exec:all`

Dig into deployment task: `grunt clean:<theme>`

The clean config is loaded: `dev/tools/grunt/configs/clean.js`. And then, the deploy command is executed:

*dev/tools/grunt/tasks/deploy.js*

```
    var deploy,
        done = this.async();

    log('Cleaning "pub/static"...');
    exec('rm -rf pub/static/*');
    ok('"pub/static" is empty.');

    log('Deploying Magento application...');
    deploy = spawn('php', ['bin/magento', 'setup:static-content:deploy']);
```

As we can see, **Grunt -`grunt clean:<theme>`- will execute two commands in order:**

**--Delete the pub static `rm -rf pub/static/`**

**--The static content deploy command: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.**

## Which one we will choose?

We can deploy static content in both ways, but **Grunt is preferred in development mode and static content deploy command in production mode**. It also makes sense because we don't need to install Node JS and do more Css style on production environment.

Comment: ok so if I get it correctly you can deploy static content in both ways but grunt is preferred in development mode and static content deploy command in production mode.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense because we don't need to install Node js and do more in our server .

Answer (score 1):

Grunt is a shortcut for magento static deploy. So, grunt exec is much faster, especially if you use '`grunt exec:vendor`'. I always use grunt, `grunt exec:vendor` and `grunt less` to compile less files.

Comment: Can grunt also used for clean static phtml files?

Comment: No, to use new changes you made in phtml files, you have to clear the cache. You can do it in Admin Panel or in console using: `php bin/magento cache:flush`