# Magento 2 compile less files on staging server

Tags: magento2, less, compiler, staging

1. I have a local repo with my Magento 2 development environment. I use
   `grunt watch` to compile my local less files.
2. I push my edited less file with `Git` to my Beanstalk remote *Develop* branch
3. I deploy (pull) those commits with Beanstalk to my staging server, so my client is able to see my changes online.

But I don't see any changes? **How do I produce my CSS (from my less files) on the staging server**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Grunt is a Node Js package**, to make the Grunt commands can work, we need to install Node Js on your Staging Server. However, this way doesn't recommend. We can deploy static content in both ways: Grunt and Deploy command, but **Grunt is preferred in development stage and static content deploy command in staging and production stage.**

In your case, we need to delete the static content `pub/static/frontend`, and run static deploy command on the Staging server. Don't need to install Node Js to use Grunt.

We can read more: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/137215/33057

Answer (score 1):

First you have to run below commands:

```
 - grunt exec:themename

 - php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

 - grunt less:themename
```

then whenever you push commits you have to run `grunt less:themename` **(if there are no new file added)**, if you add new file in commits then you have run all three command which are mentioned above.

if still not working then you have to remove `pub/static/frontend` and `var/view_preprocessed` folder and run above commands.