# What is Grunt in Magento2 and Why use?

Tags: magento2, grunt

What is Grunt in Magento2? Why use grunt. I want to know detail about Grunt. When we can use Grunt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between static content deploy & grunt exec](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137198/difference-between-static-content-deploy-grunt-exec)

Answer (score 3):

**What is Grunt in Magento2?**

Grunt is a **JavaScript task runner**, a tool used to automatically perform frequent tasks such as minification, compilation, unit testing, and linting. It uses a command-line interface to run custom tasks defined in a file (known as a Gruntfile).

**Why use grunt?**

Useing of Grunt to automate any tasks you need, but out of the box Magento comes with pre-configured grunt tasks for compiling LESS files.

And also Grunt definition is determine why we use Grunt, you can see above details.

For more detail & documentation check below link

- [devdocs.magento.com](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html)
- [devdocs.magento.com](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/tools/using_grunt.html)
- [gruntjs.com](https://gruntjs.com/getting-started)
- [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunt_(software))

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In one word: automation.

Grunt is a tool which uses for compile less`(.less)` file into css`(.css)` file which are include in `<head>` section.

In Magento2 you can configure your custom theme as per this doc: [How to configure Grunt in Magento2 ?](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/tools/using_grunt.html) and [Compile less using grunt in Magento2 ?](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html)

After successful configured grunt, whenever you change in `.less` files in your theme, it'll automatically generates `.css` files and you can see your changes at storefront.

Know more about grunt here: [Gruntjs](https://gruntjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To check more on how to use Grunt and what is grunt on Magento 2. Please read our blog [here](https://www.zealousweb.com/how-to-integrate-less-css-in-magento-2/).

Hope this will help you..!